# How to set width as a percentage of the parent in XAML

Tags: xaml, maui

How can i set the width of a view as a percentage of the parent? I tried with `WidthRequest=0.2*` but this seems to only work for grids. Is there a way to set it similarly for any other view or is my only option to set it programatically?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SnipSnip.SnippetsPage"
             Title="SnippetsPage">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="SnippetsListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Editor/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In this sample, i want the `ListView` to have a width of .2* and the `Editor` to have a width of .8*

Thanks

Comment: Grid is the right way, if you ask me. I've been using them all the time, and I haven't found any issues (performance or otherwise). Do you have any concerns about using grids?

Comment: I was merely curious if it was possible to do so with just XAML instead of having to code a way to do it. I did go with grids in the end but its a shame it cant be done with just XAML on any view..

Comment: Why do you have to code it? Define your Grid in the XAML, set the column/row definitions, and you are done.  I never (almost) write a code related to my Views. If something cannot be done in the XAML, it is not worth to do it at all. That's my philosophy.

Comment: About Grid, you can see [the official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-7.0), it tells in details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also think you should just use a grid instead. An AbsoluteLayout is just what it says: its absolute. There is no way to let it automatically use just half of the space it has or something like that. Thats what the grid is for.